# Problem with "max" function and dates with R

Tags: r, max, lubridate

I have a dataframe with dates and I simply want to know the max date:

`dates <- data.frame( randomdate = c("30-11-2018", "25-10-2018", "10-12-2015", "10-01-2020", "15-2-2013", "17-8-1999") )`

So I convert them to date format:

`dates$randomdate <- as.POSIXct(dates$randomdate,format = "%d-%m-%Y")`

And then I ask to create a column with the last date:

`dates$last_date= as.Date(max(dates$randomdate))`

The problem is that the last date in my dataset in the 10th of January 2020 and the max function just invent a date and gives me the "9th of January 2020" (this date isn't even in my dataset)

If someone can help me, maybe I don't understand how the max function works...

Kind regards

Comment: The issue is your incorrect use of `as.POSIXct` to convert to date format (the warnings should be a clue). Use `as.Date` instead.

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I didn't have any warnings, what is the difference between "as.Date" and "as.POSIXct"? Why does it give me "the day before" each time?

Comment: Sorry, you would get warnings if you omitted "format = " like I did :) `as.POSIXct` is for manipulating date-time objects, so it uses time zones. Depending on your default time zone, you may get a date different to the date for UTC. `as.Date` is for working with date objects. So if you have only dates (no times), best to use `as.Date`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments and in other answer you should use `as.Date` to convert to dates since you have dates. However, the reason why you get max date as "9th of January 2020" is because `as.POSIXct` converts object to your local timezone whereas `as.Date` uses "UTC" timezone.

You can use the same timezone in both the function to resolve it.

```
dates$randomdate <- as.POSIXct(dates$randomdate,format = '%d-%m-%Y', tz = 'UTC')
dates$last_date <- max(as.Date(dates$randomdate))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your data and fetch the last row.

```
dates$randomdate <- as.Date(dates$randomdate,format = "%d-%m-%Y")
dates <- data.frame(randomdate=dates[order(as.Date(dates$randomdate, format="%Y/%m/%d")),])
dates[nrow(dates),]
> dates[nrow(dates),]
[1] "2020-01-10"
```